# Creating a preview in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, preview

I would want to create a preview in wordpress that would look different than the normal post. I know how I can shorten the text but I want the whole post to have a different css when you click on the link that will send you to page where the post is. I will appreciate any answer or hint. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/). Its not available on posts, only on pages but it will look the same. Create a new page, select a different template and click preview.